# Auto add url parameter to all internal links

Tags: php

For example, if I open mysite.com/?parameter=123

How to make all internal links on this page end with "?formreg=123", include links on the post, menu link etc, using PHP?

```
<?php
$formreg = $_GET[parameter];

function AppendCampaignToString($string) {
    $regex = '#(<a href=")([^"]*)("[^>]*?>)#i';
    return preg_replace_callback($regex, '_appendCampaignToString', $string);
}
function _AppendCampaignToString($match) {
    $url = $match[2];
    if (strpos($url, '?') === false) {
        $url .= '?';
    }
    $url .= 'formreg=$formreg';
    return $match[1].$url.$match[3];
}
?>
```

Any advice?

Comment: Where's the html?

Comment: Unrelated I think, but `$url .= 'formreg=$formreg';` perhaps should be `$url .= 'formreg=' . $formreg;`

Answer (score 0):

Make a function

```
function createUrl($string) {
    // Do any URL logic you want
    return $string . '?parameter=123';
}
```

And make sure every URL you use is wrapped in this.

```
<a href="<?php echo createUrl('profile'); ?>">Profile</a>
```

This is a basic example. You may want to scope the function inside the class, prepend the string with the base URL, and other Good Ideas, but the code above is the concept I think you're looking for.

Comment: This code will require me to edit all links in the page, so it's not auto add the parameter, and not sure how to apply it to Menus.

Comment: Where are the links currently stored. Are they in HTML inside a database or in HTML inside a file?